# How would I get the detailed version of my Python interpreter via a one-liner or command-line option?

Tags: python

The output of --version itself is a little too brief:

```
C:\>python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

However, if I run Python from the command prompt, I get something similar to the following, with verbose version info for the interpreter all on one line:

```
C:\> python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Is there a simple way, *in a one-line command or via some options* to get that same verbose version info line as a string that I could use to populate an environment variable or such?

**In effect, is there a more verbose variant of --version I'm unaware of?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
```

is the basics; or to get closer to the same thing:

```
python -c "import sys;print('Python '+sys.version.replace('\n','')+' on '+sys.platform)"
```

Comment: Thank you, that does it! It seemed like a common question yet my searches came up empty / noisy (I mainly wondered if there was a command-line option I missed, and the string itself is super-common). FYI, for Windows one would need to use double-quotes thus: python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"

Comment: For the second option, to be exact (and cross-platform - quoting it this way works on Linux as well as Windows)): python -c "import sys;print('Python '+sys.version.replace('\n','')+' on '+sys.platform)"